# Override jQuery's selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

When I select an item on a selectmenu, I want to append some text to the selected option.

I don't want to change the option's text, just the text that is displayed in the `.ui-selectmenu-text` element.

For example, if the options are

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
```

If I choose the second one, I want the select menu to show `Option B ("some text")`

I tried using something like

```
$.widget("ui.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu,
{
    TEST: function()
    {
        console.log("just to check if this happens");
    },
});
```

where the `TEST` part is, I've tried `_select`, `_setOption` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close! This is how I've done it

```
$.widget("ui.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu,
{
    _select: function(event, ui)
    {
        this._super(event, ui);

        this.buttonText.text(this.buttonText.text() + "(some text)");
    },
});
```